# Select one data point per row using indexing vector with negative values

Tags: r, matrix, indexing

Suppose you have a matrix `a`

```
a <- matrix(1:9, 3, 3)
a
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    7
[2,]    2    5    8
[3,]    3    6    9
```

and a vector `b` indicating which element of each row you want to extract. That is, the vector `b` indicates the column of the element, for instance:

```
b <- c(1, 3, 1)
```

If we want to extract the indicated data points, we can simply index each desired element like this:

```
a[cbind(1:nrow(a),b)]
[1] 1 8 3
```

I would like to do it with a negative index vector. That is, R should return a matrix where exactly one element per row is omitted (in this case, a 3x2 matrix). If I try it in a naive approach, R throws an error:

```
c = -b
a[cbind(1:nrow(a),c)]
Error in a[cbind(1:nrow(a), c)] : 
  negative values are not allowed in a matrix subscript
```

Thank you!

Comment: Omitted in what sense? Replaced with NA, empty space, some number?

Comment: Empty Space, I would like to input my 3x3 matrix and get a 3x2 matrix as output where in each row the element indicated in the vector `b` is omitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is another naive approach. We loop over every row in the matrix and remove index specified in `b`.

```
t(sapply(seq_len(nrow(a)), function(x) a[x, -b[x]]))

#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    4    7
#[2,]    2    5
#[3,]    6    9
```

Or using `mapply` with `split`

```
t(mapply(`[`, split(a, seq_len(nrow(a))), -b))
```

Answer (score 2):

Not pretty, but you could do

```
b <- c(1, 3, 1) + 3 * 0:2
matrix(c(t(a))[-b], 3, 2, byrow = TRUE)
```